# Git show file names and number of changes

Tags: git

I am trying to get the file names and number of changes per file from a commit.

Ideally I would would an output like:

```
file1.txt +10 -20
file2.txt +239 -15
```

So far I have:
`git show --pretty="format:" --name-only`

but this only gets me the file names.

Comment: Just using `--numstat` is the easy way to get close to what you want.

Comment: `git show --pretty=format:"" --numstat` output something close enough to what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the that result by getting the format with the `numstat` flag, and then passing them through awk to reverse them.

`git show COMMIT_ID --pretty="format:" --numstat | awk '{name=$3; insertions=$1; deletions=-$2; print name, insertions, deletions}'`

Comment: @GeorgeL You shouldn't feed the output of porcelain commands such as `git show` to a parser. If the Git developers change the output of that command, your parser will be broken. Better stick with plumbing commands as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

`git diff` will show you the number of lined removed or added.
Use awk, sed or any other unix command to extract the data from the input

`--shortstat` is what you want:

```
git diff --shortstat commit1 commit2
```

`git cat-file -s` will output the size in bytes of an object in git.
`git diff-tree` can tell you the differences between one tree and another.

Putting this together into a script called `git-file-size-diff`.

We can try something like the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

args=$(git rev-parse --sq "$@")

# the diff-tree will output line like:
# :040000 040000 4...acd0 fd...94 M main.webapp

# parse the parameters form the diff-tree
eval "git diff-tree -r $args" | {
  total=0

  # read all the above params as described in thi sline:
  # :040000 040000 4...acd0 fd...94 M   main.webapp
  while read A B C D M P
  do
    case $M in
      # modified file
      M) bytes=$(( $(git cat-file -s $D) - $(git cat-file -s $C) )) ;;

      # Added file
      A) bytes=$(git cat-file -s $D) ;;

      # deleted file
      D) bytes=-$(git cat-file -s $C) ;;
      *)

      # Error - no file status found
      echo >&2 warning: unhandled mode $M in \"$A $B $C $D $M $P\"
      continue
      ;;

    # close the case statment
    esac

    # sum the total bytes so far
    total=$(( $total + $bytes ))

    # print out the (bytes) & the name of the file ($P)
    printf '%d\t%s\n' $bytes "$P"
  done

  # print out the grand total
  echo total $total
}
```

In use this looks like the following:

```
$ git file-size-diff HEAD~850..HEAD~845
-234   a.txt
112    folder/file.txt
-4     README.md
28     b.txt
total -98
```

By using `git-rev-parse` it should accept all the usual ways of specifying commit ranges.

**Note**:
that bash runs the while read in a subshell, hence the additional curly braces to avoid losing the total when the subshell exits.

Comment: Great answer! Unfortunately, the simplicity and copy-paste readiness of the other answer works perfectly for me, since I am using this in conjunction with a python git library.

Comment: Cool. as long as you found your answer